# ¿Existe alguna palabra para nombrar la comida que se toma después de cenar?

Tags: comida, solicitud-de-término

En catalán utilizamos la palabra [*ressopó*](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0118126) para designar la comida que se realiza después de cenar.

Me explico:

Uno llega a casa por la noche, cena con normalidad y luego sigue con sus cosas. La noche se alarga y antes de acostarse uno se da cuenta de que ya vuelve a tener hambre, por lo que se prepara un *algo*: un bocadillo, unas galletas... Tal y como comenta la [Viquipèdia](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ressop%C3%B3), esta comida no tiene una función social sino de matar el hambre, por lo que no hay ceremonia ni orden establecido.

Desde el momento que [*cena*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8Bs26eN%7C8Bvhg6D) se define como *Última comida del día, que se toma al atardecer o por la noche*, esta ultimísima comida es algo así como un [*tentempié*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZUM7MgT).

¿Existe pues alguna palabra para definir esto?

Algunas notas:

- Cuando digo *la comida que se toma después de cenar* no me refiero al alimento en sí, sino al acto o la reunión. Lo que en inglés sería *meal*, aproximadamente.
- En algunos lugares se dice [*comida*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9w3sObI) a la *cena*. Sea como fuere, me refiero a la última comida del día.
- Probablemente en España es difícil encontrar una palabra para esto, pues tradicionalmente se cena bastante tarde. En lugares del norte de Europa, donde se cena hacia las seis de la tarde, esto puede tener más sentido. Desconozco las tradiciones horarias en Hispanoamérica.

Comment: En Colombia se le dice _merienda_ pero buscando en la RAE parece que utilizamos mal esa palabra.

Comment: @DGaleano curioso. En España la _merienda_ va después de la comida; teniendo en cuenta que en Colombia decís comida a nuestra cena, sería equivalente :) Aunque sí, veo que la RAE lo define claramente: _Comida ligera que se toma a media tarde._

Comment: Merienda para nosotros es tal cual lo defines en tu pregunta. La merienda "colombiana" es después de la comida/cena antes de irse a la cama. La comida de la media tarde que según la RAE es la merienda aquí le decimos **el algo** ej. ¿Que vamos a tomar de algo?

Comment: En Argentina se dice "pinto bajón"

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con tu uso de *meal*.  // ¿Puede ser algo dulce o salado, no importa cuál? // ¿Entendí bien, te refieres a algo que se toma sin ceremonia, para matar el hambre o por antojo?  En inglés (EEUU) esto se llama *bedtime snack*.  Si a eso te refieres, quizás ayudaría incluir ese punto de referencia.

Comment: El postre está incluido en la cena, ¿no? En Argentina se suele cenar muy tarde para los estándares de otros países y no hay generalmente nada después, si no se considera un postre que puede ser servido un rato más tarde.

Comment: @pablodf76 sí, para mí el postre sería parte de la cena. Si bien la _recena_ puede ser cualquier cosa, suele consistir en algo dulce. Recuerdo por ejemplo en mi piso de estudiantes, donde cenábamos digamos que a las nueva de la noche y a eso de las once nos tomábamos un vaso de leche con (muchas) galletas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Esta me la sé porque tuvimos que contratar una para nuestra boda, que fue por la tarde/noche:

> **[recena](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VP6fIw4)**
>
> 1. f. Esp. Segunda cena que se hace cuando pasa mucho tiempo entre la cena y el momento de acostarse.

Nótese que aplica solo en España. Otra opción:

> **[resopón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WBjN3ja)**
>
> Del cat. *resopó*, de *re-* 're-' y *sopar* 'cenar'.
>
> 1. m. Esp. Segunda cena, más ligera, que se hace generalmente tras una fiesta o cuando pasa mucho tiempo entre la cena y la hora de acostarse.

Se ve que el término catalán ha sido también aceptado en el español de España.

> *Con esto y un bizcocho, hasta mañana a las ocho. Y si no cedió a ningún otro producto como desayuno o merienda, se puso de moda para la **recena**, **resopón** o cena tardía a la salida del teatro, para prolongar la velada en las chocolaterías.*
>
> -  Antonio Beltrán Martínez, "Pueblos de Aragón II", España (2000)

Comment: ¡Ostras! Pues no sabía que existiera esta palabra en castellano, me la quedo :)

Answer (score 7):

Bueno, ya que parece que la respuesta va a ser por regiones...

En Colombia *los que pueden* hacen las siguientes comidas a lo largo del día

- *Tomar tragos* (no confundir con *tomar trago*): Principalmente en el campo cuando hay que ir muy temprano (4-5 am) a hacer labores como ordeñar las vacas las personas toman un café o un agua de panela y a eso le dicen tragos. Al regresar tomarán el desayuno.
- *Desayuno*: Primera comida del día.
- *La media mañana*/*Las medias nueves*: Se hace a mitad de la mañana.
- *Almuerzo*: alrededor del mediodía.
- *El algo*/*Las onces*: a mitad de la tarde.
- *Comida*/(*cena* solo si es elegante): al comienzo de la noche.
- *Merienda*: comida ligera antes de irse a dormir.

Según la RAE **merienda** es a la mitad de la tarde por lo que parece que en Colombia la hemos usado mal desde siempre y aún la RAE no la registra como uso regional.

Comment: Interesantísima respuesta, DGaleano. Me parece sumamente peculiar el hecho de que _cena_ lo sea solo si es elegante.

Comment: Lo registra el diccionario de americanismos: [merienda](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=merienda) en Colombia es el "alimento que se toma después de la comida como refrigerio", siendo [comida](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=comida) el "alimento que se toma entre las 17 y las 21 horas". Así que no la habéis usado mal, simplemente la habéis adaptado.

Comment: Gracias @CarlosAlejo por validar la respuesta. No se me ocurrió buscar ahí.

Comment: @fedorqui Así hablamos. A la última comida del día siempre le decimos "la comida" obviamente se entiende "la cena" pero de manera corriente nadie dice "vamos a cenar" sino que casi todos decimos "vamos a comer". Cuando se trata de alguna celebración o similar, si es más frecuente hablar de "una cena"

Comment: Por cierto, me apunto lo de _las medias nueves_ y _las onces_ para futuras preguntas :)

Comment: En Cuba merienda puede ser a cualquier hora del día... a todo lo que no sea desayuno, almuerzo y comida (nunca se dice cena) se le llama merienda.

Answer (score 6):

[**Sobrecenar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y6rOg5Y)

> 1. intr. Cenar por segunda vez. U. t. c. tr.

Answer (score 5):

Cuando se cena después de cenar (cenar por segunda vez), según la RAE se dice [***zahorar***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cHoQfnR):

> 2. intr. desus. Sobrecenar, cenar por segunda vez, a deshora.

Comment: Oi e bem-vinda a Spanish S.E. As respostas deveriam estar em espanhol ou inglês.

Comment: Es un término en desuso, pero efectivamente significa lo que se pedía. ¡Gracias por tu aportación, y bienvenida!